# Why does image.js show an error about import

Tags: javascript

```
import { Image } from 'image-js';


Image.load('test.png').then(async (img) => {
  const grey = img.grey();
  await grey.save('grey.png');
});
```

i have imported image.js from npm and i am receiving
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at js.js:1:1)
why is the import statement not working even though i have written my code from the docs

Answer (score 0):

Using `import` only works in module, I assume you are using node.js, so go to your `package.json` file, and set/add `"type": "module"`

```json
{
  "name": "t",
  "version": "",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module", // only change this
  "main": "test.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: is using type="module" in the script tag fine?

Comment: What is your environment? Are you using NodeJS? Or you are trying to use an NPM module in the Browser?